# Simple square root loop

Tags: swift, loops, square-root

I'm trying to create a loop that squares each number in my range variable then finds the square root of that number.

```
import UIKit

var range = 0..<10
var square = 0.0
var root = 0.0

for i in range {
    square = i * i
    root = sqrt(square)
    print(square)
}
```

My error right now is "Cannot assign value of type Int to Double". I also get an error when converting my range variable to doubles.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Use type specifiers and `Double(i*i)`

Answer (score 0):

```
var range = 0..<10
var square: Double = 0.0
var root: Double = 0.0

for i in range {
    square = Double(i * i)
    root = sqrt(square)
    print(square)
}
```

What you want to do is overtype the integer to Double, because square i already Double (as pointed out explicitly in my answer)

it's really simple, you cannot search Double while in range loop, that would be really odd... What you may want to do is use stride function, see

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1641347-stride

Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try `square = Double(i * i)` instead of `square = i * i`.